# Why did Gleep almost fry Tanda?

Tags: myth-adventures

In the later *MythAdventures* novels, there are several references to Gleep almost frying Tanda with his breath. Chumley manages to knock Tanda out of the way, saving her, but also managing to injure her.

Do we ever learn why Gleep does this?

Comment: Tananda shows up with burns in *M.Y.T.H. Inc. In Action*, the 10th book, and I've seen references to Gleep redeeming himself in the 11th book. I'll try to get around to rereading them to see if I see anything.

Answer (score 5):

The story this happens in is *Little Myth Marker*. Gleep isn't aiming at Tananda but at Markie, the character assassin posing as a little girl, who was placed temporarily under Skeeve's protection by her 'father', ostensibly as a marker to cover his poker debt. Markie, also known as 'The Axe', was hired to assassinate Skeeve's character by a group of envious magicians. She nearly succeeds by using the technique of staging a series of embarrassing accidents. Gleep, who sees through her ruses, attempts to protect Skeeve by attacking Markie, though his efforts are misinterpreted as an attack on Tananda, who was with Markie during the attack and reflexively shielded her from Gleep's wrath.

Comment: I remember that, but that was in an older book, and it was Bunny, not Tanda. I'm talking about in the much more recent books, where MYTH Inc is trying to stop Queen Hemlock's expansion plan by sabotaging the army.

Comment: You're right--it had been awhile since I read the novels and had confused these incidents.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for your question is in *M.Y.T.H. Inc. Link*, the 7th book in the series, in the chapter of "Gleep's Tale", where Nunzio gives him a speech about Skeeve's odd behavior and Gleep considers it.

> “I just don’t know what’s goin’ on lately, Gleep. Know what I mean? On the paperwork things couldn’t be goin’ better, except lately everybody’s been actin’ crazy. First the Boss buys a casino we built for somebody else, then overnight he wants to sell it. Bunny and Tananda are goin’ at each other for a while, then all of a sudden Bunny’s actin’ quiet and depressed and Tananda…did you know she wanted to borrow money from me the other day? Right after she gets done with that collection job? I don’t know what she did with her commission or why she doesn’t ask the Boss for an advance or even what she needs the money for. Just ‘Can you spot me some cash, Nunzio? No questions asked?’, and when I try to offer my services as a confidential type, she sez ‘In that case, forget it. I’ll ask someone else!’ and leaves all huffy-like. I’ll tell ya, Gleep, there’s sumpin’ afoot, and I’m not sure I like it.”
>
> He was raising some fascinating points, points which I’ll freely admit had escaped my notice. While I had devoted a certain portion of my intellect to deciphering the intricacies of human conduct, there was much in the subtleties of their intra-species relationships which elude me…particularly when it came to individuals other than Skeeve. Reflecting on Nunzio’s words, I realized that my pet had not been to see me much lately, which was in itself a break in pattern. Usually he would make time to visit, talking to me about the problems he had been facing and the self-doubts he felt. I wondered if his increased absences were an offshoot of the phenomenon Nunzio was describing. It was food for thought, and something I promised myself I would consider carefully at a later point.

And here he discuss about eliminating the threats:

> Perhaps Nunzio was right. It was possible that my pet was reacting adversely to the change in his status from free-lance operator to the head of a corporation, much the same as tropical fish will suffer if the pH of the water in their aquarium is changed too suddenly. I was very much aware that an organism’s environment consisted of much more than their physical surroundings…social atmosphere, for example, often influenced a human’s well-being. If that were the case, then it behooved me to do something about it.
>
> Exactly how I was to make the necessary adjustments would be a problem. Whenever possible, I tried to allow my pet free will. That is, I liked to give him the illusion of choosing his own course and associates without interference from me. Occasionally I would stray from this stance, such as when they brought that horrible Markie creature into our home, but for the most part it was an unshakeable policy. This meant that if I indeed decided that it was time to winnow out or remove any or all of Skeeve’s current associates for his own good, it would have to be done in a manner which could not be traced to me. This would not only preserve the illusion that I was not interfering in his life, but also save him the angst which would be generated if he realized I was responsible for the elimination of one or more of his friends. Yes, this would require considerable thought and consideration.

Comment: This is a great answer, but "it would have to be done in a manner which could not be traced to me". I don't think frying Tanda with his breath really counts. That seems like the least subtle way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

While the information is correct, the actual incident between Tanda and Gleep was never spelled out in story form...just discussed by the characters after the fact.   It can be assumed Gleep was enacting a decision to eliminate Skeeve's associates, but it wasn't spelled out what drove him to the decision and why he started with Tananda.  I own all the books, but I've been listening to the series on audible recently. It's one of the questions that's always bugged me as well.

Comment: This seems logical! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Gleep planning subtle genocide of Skeeve's friends and then fry Tananda and Markie does not fit. My opinion: Gleep is still a very young dragon - he can not speak yet. So planning is good, but execution is bad. Beware of the Gleep in 1000 years!

Comment: Most of this seems to be an agreement to the question rather than an answer but I think you have one contained in _"Gleep is still a very young dragon - he can not speak yet. So planning is good, but execution is bad."_ Could you flesh it out a bit more and maybe [edit] in some evidence as that would go a long way to making as better answer?